# Для чего нужна, и нужна ли функция "языковые атрибуты"?

Tags: xhtml, php

Объясните, пожалуйста, значение функции.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes('xhtml'); ?>>
```

Вот её [описание](http://phpdoc.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/Template/_wp-includes---general-template.php.html#functionlanguage_attributes), однако я все равно не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Эти параметры указывают на:

1. Пространство имен xhtml (`xmlns`)
2. Язык документа, в случае если `<?php language_attributes('xhtml'); ?>` возвращает строчку типа `xml:lang="ru-RU"`